# SQL query to get sql year version

Tags: sql, sql-server, version

I'm using SQL Server and I need a SQL query which returns the year of the version.

I'm familiar with the next methods:

```
select @@version

select SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')
```

but I need a query that will return for example:

```
2008
```

or

```
2005
```

The first query I mentioned requires dirty parsing and the second returns some product number.

Do anyone knows such a query?

Thanks!

Comment: What year should be returned for 2008 R2?

Comment: The year that should be returned for 2008R2 is 2008

Comment: I think it will end in something like
Select Cast(SubString(@@version,CharIndex('2',@@Version),4) as int)

Comment: @bummi, thanks! but I don't know if it safe enough to parse it that way. I need to verify with all possible @@version result that the first '2' digit is part if the year.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this - it just inspects the first two characters of the version number and returns the corresponding "year" for the SQL Server version.

```
SELECT
    'SQL Server Year ' + 
    CASE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')), 1, 2)
          WHEN '8.' THEN '2000'
          WHEN '9.' THEN '2005'
          WHEN '10' THEN '2008'
          WHEN '11' THEN '2012'
          WHEN '12' THEN '2014'
          WHEN '13' THEN '2016'
          WHEN '14' THEN '2017'
          WHEN '15' THEN '2019'
    END
```

Of course, you can package this up into a user-defined function to make it "prettier"

Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

Since the first number of the property [`SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx)  is the major version number:

> ***major.minor.build.revision***

Then you can create a temp table containing each edition major version number and its year. Then you will end up with the folowing query:

```
 DECLARE @productversion VARCHAR(100);
 SELECT @productversion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS VARCHAR(100));
SELECT years.year, years.name
FROM 
(
  VALUES(9, '2005', 'SQL Server 2005'), 
        (10, '2008', 'SQL Server 2008 OR SQL Server 2008 R2'),
        ... 
) AS years(majornumber, [year], name)
WHERE years.majornumber = LEFT(@productversion, 
                               CHARINDEX('.', @productversion , 1) - 1);
```

Comment: Also: 8 = SQL Server 2000, 11 = SQL Server 2012

Comment: Thanks! I will use it.
Where did you find the match between the major and year version?

Comment: @kernelMode - I googled it. Here is a page for example [**SQL Server Versions**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/783.sql-server-versions.aspx). But note that you are looking for the first two numbers, the major.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'SQL Server ' + 
    CASE CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS CHAR(2))
          WHEN '8.' THEN '2000'
          WHEN '9.' THEN '2005'
          WHEN '10' THEN '2008/2008R2'
          WHEN '11' THEN '2012'
          WHEN '12' THEN '2014'
          WHEN '13' THEN '2016'
    END
```

Output -

```
----------------------
SQL Server 2016
```